# run cmake-tools targets in same terminal

Tags: visual-studio-code, cmake

I'm remotely developing a project based on yocto and I'm trying to set up remote debugger for my x86 target.

Obviously it is not working, but I can't see any logs - launching any target via cmake-tools GUI runs a new terminal and removes the command issued by the addon, so I can't really see what cmake-tools is trying to do.

e.g. if I run a simple UT - all the output I get is test result, but I can't see the path to the binary file.

Is there a way to keep all the output in a single terminal, and to not remove commands issued by the addon?

Comment: Can you provide some details that could help us reproduce the issue? The help page for making [mre]s might have some tips for you on how to do that. I'd suggest changing "UT" to "unit test" for clarity's sake.

Comment: If you're trying to see what the CMake-tools extension is doing, you might find the extension's [troubleshooting documentation](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cmake-tools/blob/main/docs/troubleshoot.md) helpful.